# Make entries from foreign model optional

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have following **models.py**:

```
class trainee(models.Model):
        username = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'username')

class learningObjective(models.Model):
        trainee = models.ForeignKey(trainee, verbose_name = "Azubi")
        learningObjectives = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Lernziel')

class completedTask(models.Model):
        trainee = models.ForeignKey(trainee, verbose_name = "Azubi")
        learningObjectivecompletedTask = models.ManyToManyField(learningObjective, verbose_name = "Lernziel")
        date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Datum')
        duration = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Dauer')
        documentationReference = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Dokumentationsverweis', blank = True)
        educationDepartment = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Ausbildungsabteilung')
        completedtasks = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Ausgefuehrte Taetigkeiten')
```

And this is a part of my **views.py**:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_at(request):
        trainee_objects = trainee.objects.all()
        usernameID = 1
        for traineeUser in trainee_objects:
                if traineeUser.username == request.user.username:
                        usernameID = traineeUser.id
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = completedTaskForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        neueAT=completedTask(date=request.POST['Datum'], duration=request.POST['Dauer'], educationDepartment=request.POST['Abteilung'], completedtasks=request.POST['AT'], trainee_id=usernameID)
                        neueAT.save()
                        for ct in learningObjective.objects.filter(learningObjectives=request.POST.get['Lernziel']):
                                 neueAT.learningObjectivecompletedTask.add(ct)
                 else:
                        form = completedTask()
         return render(request, 'at.html', {'at': completedTask.objects.all(), 'Lernziel': learningObjective.objects.all()})
```

So, I have got now a fields which I have to fill for for the model **completedTask**. It is all working fine till someone is not filling in the data which is actually required. I am writing an APP to document what you have done in your productive time and of course you should make all your entries immediately and correctly. But if it is not possible to make one entry immediately there shouldn't be an error thrown. How is it possible to make several fields optional. I thought that I simply could create a default value which gets deleted when the user is updating his entries. But I prefer not to do that. It would be cool to have a blank entry in my database, which is the case right now. But when I do it like this it gives me following error:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /programm/create_at

It creates the entries and everything, which is all good but I want to get rid of the error. Is there maybe a template tag, which checks whether the fields got an input or not ? I tried to search for it with out any success. If you need more informations, please tell me.

**Edit:** (These are my forms, first time working with them)

```
from django import forms
from programm.models import trainee, todoList, learningObjective, topic, person, completedTask, remark

class completedTaskForm(forms.Form):
        trainee = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        learningObjectivecompletedTask = forms.CharField(required = False)
        date = forms.DateField(required = True)
        duration = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        documentationReference = forms.CharField(required = False)
        educationDepartment = forms.CharField(required = True)
        completedtasks = forms.CharField(required = True)
```

There no entries any more. The output of `print(form.error)` is following:

> date
>
> This
>   field is required.
>
> duration
>
> This field is required.
>
> completedtasks
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> educationDepartment
>
> This field is required.

Please guide me, I'm pretty stuck at the moment.

Comment: Take a look at forms here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: That is the exact same thing I am doing since 2 hours. I am retarded enough to not figure out the solution for my problem :P I am working on it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo I am so proud of myself :P The solution were the **Forms**

```
from django import forms
from programm.models import trainee, todoList, learningObjective, topic, person, completedTask, remark

class completedTaskForm(forms.Form):
        trainee = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        learningObjectivecompletedTask = forms.CharField(required = False)
        date = forms.DateField(required = True)
        duration = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        documentationReference = forms.CharField(required = False)
        educationDepartment = forms.CharField(required = True)
        completedtasks = forms.CharField(required = True)
```

And this edit in my **Views**:

```
trainee_objects = trainee.objects.all()
        usernameID = 1
        for traineeUser in trainee_objects:
                if traineeUser.username == request.user.username:
                        usernameID = traineeUser.id

        if request.method == 'POST':
                forms = completedTaskForm(request.POST)
                if forms.is_valid():
                        formlearningObjectives = forms.cleaned_data['formlearningObjectives']
                        formdate = forms.cleaned_data['formdate']
                        formduration = forms.cleaned_data['formduration']
                        formeducationDepartment = forms.cleaned_data['formeducationDepartment']
                        formcompletedtasks = forms.cleaned_data['formcompletedtasks']

                        neueAT=completedTask(date=formdate, duration=formduration, educationDepartment=formeducationDepartment, completedtasks=formcompletedtasks, trainee_id=usernameID)
                        neueAT.save()
                        for ct in learningObjective.objects.filter(learningObjectives=formlearningObjectives):
                                neueAT.learningObjectivecompletedTask.add(ct)
                else:
                        form = completedTask()
                        print("Es hat fehlgeschlagen!" + formset.errors)
        return render(request, 'at.html', {'at': completedTask.objects.all(), 'Lernziel': learningObjective.objects.all()})
```